# I've formatted my SD card as internal on CM13 nightly and now it won't update

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, twrp, motorola-moto-g2

So the update is stored in storage/emulated/0/cmupdater and if I try to update via the Settings it just boots into TWRP and does nothing. I tried manually browsing to flash the zip but I can't seem to find it. 
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried reformatting your SD card how it was before? Presumably it needs to be in that file system for TWRP to understand it.

Comment: Also, have you mounted the SD card in TWRP? You can do so in the mount menu, by checking Data

Comment: I had similar issue few days ago. Basically I ended with broken SD card. I will try to reformat it when I get the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to TWRP 3.02 solved this for me